# Get Month From Strings of Varying Lengths

Tags: php

Is there a way with PHP to get the month out of a string. They vary in length so I can't use substr. Here are some examples of what I would want.

iTunes US July 2013 -> July

Rdio June 2013 -> June

Spotify Streaming June 2013 -> June

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: what is a regular expression

Comment: Regular expressions are used for matching patterns in strings. See www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression match:

```
preg_match('/January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December/', $string, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take array of all months and see if your string contains that month

```
$montharray= array( 'January', 'February','March', 'April',
                  'May',    'June',   'July',   'August',
                  'September',  'October', 'November',
                 'December');
    for($i=0;i<count($montharray);$i++){
    $pos = strrpos($mystring, montharray[i]);
        if ($pos === true) {
            //found month
            $month = montharray[i];
            break;
          }
    }
```

Comment: Your `for` loop assumes the array is indexed from 0, but it's actually indexed from 1. Use `foreach` instead.

Comment: Also, `strrpos` returns the position, not `true`, when it finds a match.